# Does FDIC insurance at one bank cover each account?

Tags: united-states, banking, financial-literacy, fdic

I was reading that FDIC insurance covers accounts up to $250,000. Does this mean each account you have at a bank is insured up to $250,000 or is $250,000 the maximum for all accounts at a bank?

Also, if you reached the maximum at one bank, could you open an account at another bank and be insured for up to $250,000 at each bank?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does this mean each account you have at a bank is insured up to $250,000 or is $250,000 the maximum for all accounts at a bank?

It is maximum of $250,000 across all accounts held by an individual or ownership at a bank. So if you are married you can get a max of $750,000 if you open the accounts as below in the same bank;

- One [or more] accounts in your name
- One [or more] Account in your spouses name
- One [or more] Joint Account with you and spouse

For more details read more at [FDIC](https://www.fdic.gov/deposit/covered/categories.html) website.
Note: The join account is per unique ownership combination. So if you open another joint account at the same bank with your dad [or mom]; you will get additional cover of $250,000 like wise if you open a joint account with your spouse and dad; its again additional $250,000

> Also, if you reached the maximum at one bank, could you open an account at another bank and be insured for up to $250,000 at each bank?

Yes you can do that; and it is separate from your other bank. So if you have 2 accounts at 2 different banks, it would be upto $500,000.

Although most banks are registered for FDIC, it makes sense to check if [your bank is covered](https://research.fdic.gov/bankfind/). More so if you are dealing with a small credit union type of institution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with a bank then you are interested in [FDIC coverage](https://www.fdic.gov/deposit/covered/categories.html). If you are dealing with a credit Union it is [NCUA coverage](https://www.mycreditunion.gov/estimator/Pages/info.aspx).

Both NCUA coverage and FDIC Coverage have a $250,000 limit. Both types of institutions have coverage that can exceed the $250K amount if they have multiple account types with that one institution:

> **What are the basic NCUA coverage limits?***
>
> Single Ownership Accounts (owned by one person with no beneficiaries):
>   $250,000 per member-owner
>
> Joint Ownership Accounts (two or more persons with no beneficiaries):
>   $250,000 per owner (with the primary owner a member of the credit
>   union)
>
> IRAs and other certain retirement accounts: $250,000 per member-owner
>
> Revocable trust accounts: Each member-owner is insured up to $250,000
>   for each eligible beneficiary named or identified in the revocable
>   trust, subject to limitations and requirements.
>
> Irrevocable trust accounts: Each owner (so long as all owners OR all
>   beneficiaries are members of the credit union) is insured up to
>   $250,000 for each beneficiary named or identified in the irrevocable
>   trust, subject to specific limitations and requirements. Coverdell
>   Education Savings Accounts, formerly education IRAs, are insured as
>   irrevocable trust accounts.
>
> A qualifying eligible beneficiary must be a natural person, or a
>   charitable organization or non-profit entity under the Internal
>   Revenue Code.
>
> *These share insurance coverage limits refer to the total of all shares that account owners have at each federally insured credit
>   union. The listing above shows only the most common ownership types
>   that apply to individual and family shares, and assumes that all NCUA
>   requirements are met.

One important item is that a bank or credit union can have products they sell that don't have the $250K coverage:

> **What types of accounts are eligible for NCUA insurance?***
>
> NCUA share insurance covers many types of share deposits received at a
>   federally insured credit union, including deposits in a share draft
>   account, share savings account, or time deposit such as a share
>   certificate. NCUA insurance covers members' accounts at each federally
>   insured credit union, dollar-for-dollar, including principal and any
>   accrued dividend through the date of the insured credit union’s
>   closing, up to the insurance limit. This coverage also applies to
>   nonmember deposits when permitted by law.
>
> NCUA does not insure money invested in stocks, bonds, mutual funds,
>   life insurance policies, annuities or municipal securities, even if
>   these investment or insurance products are sold at a federally insured
>   credit union. Credit unions often provide these services to their
>   members through third-parties, and the investment and insurance
>   products are not insured by the NCUSIF. In locations where these
>   investment and insurance products are offered or sold to members,
>   credit unions are required to disclose that the products:
>
> -- are not insured by NCUA;
>
> -- are not deposits or other obligations of the credit union and are not guaranteed by the credit union; and
>
> -- are subject to investment risks, including possible loss of the principal invested.
>
> In addition, NCUA does not insure safe deposit boxes or their
>   contents.